# Trying to Generate an NFT Using .CSV Metadata and Pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have been scratching my head at generating my actual NFT's from a .csv file for a long time and looking for resources has been challenging at the very least for my Hardcoding Method (Following a Guide)  If Anyone could Look through what I have and Offer some Help Figuring out what's going on I would be FOREVER Endebted to you!

```
    def generateOneRandRow(ADATvID):
    FILENAME = "ADA Tv" + str(ADATvID)
    NO = ADATvID
    BACKGROUND = randBackground()
    ACCESSORIES = randAccessories()
    HEAD = randHead()
    HAT = randHat()
    BODY = randBody()
    CHEST = randChest()
    ARMS = randArms()
    FACE = randFace()
    singleRow = [FILENAME,NO,BACKGROUND,ACCESSORIES,HEAD,HAT,BODY,CHEST,ARMS,FACE]

testThisRow =["ADA Tv2925","2925","cnft","couchbear","bnw","mullet","damagedorange","bluesuit","greenlightsaber","inlove"]


def checkIfExists(checkRow):
    aData = pd.read_csv('adalist.csv')

    index_list = aData[(aData['Background'] == checkRow[2])] & (aData['Accessories'] == checkRow[3]) & (aData['Head'] == checkRow[4]) & (aData['Hat'] == checkRow[5]) & (aData['Body'] == checkRow[6]) &(aData['Chest'] ==checkRow[7]) & (aData['Arms'] ==checkRow[7]) & (aData['Face'] == checkRow[8]).index.tolist()
    print(index_list)

    if index_list == []:
        return False
    else:
        return True

checkIfExists(testThisRow)
```

[Error Messages... Help a Python Noob Out Please! and Feel Free To FLAME Me If It's Super Obvious.  THANKS!!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LBnZd.png)

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
index_list = aData[(aData['Background'] == checkRow[2])] & (aData['Accessories'] == checkRow[3]) & (aData['Head'] == checkRow[4]) & (aData['Hat'] == checkRow[5]) & (aData['Body'] == checkRow[6]) &(aData['Chest'] ==checkRow[7]) & (aData['Arms'] ==checkRow[7]) & (aData['Face'] == checkRow[8]).index.tolist()
```

to:

```
index_list = aData[(aData['Background'] == checkRow[2])
& (aData['Accessories'] == checkRow[3]) & 
(aData['Head'] == checkRow[4]) & 
(aData['Hat'] == checkRow[5]) & 
(aData['Body'] == checkRow[6]) &
(aData['Chest'] ==checkRow[7]) & 
(aData['Arms'] ==checkRow[7]) & 
(aData['Face'] == checkRow[8])].index.tolist()
```

Because you did not provide data, i reproduced your error as follows:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,'2'], 'b':[5,6]})
df[(df['a']=='2')]&(df['b']==6).index.tolist()
```

With error:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for &: 'str' and 'int'
```

Editing the brackets:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,'2'], 'b':[5,6]})
df[(df['a']=='2')&(df['b']==6)].index.tolist()
```

With no error.

Comment: This worked Like a Charm for this issue!!!  I Guess I just didn't see my errors, and just needed some fresh eyes!  Thank you for the help and clear explanation keramat!  I'll be sure to include my .csv data file the next time I run into an issue like this!